# CMakeLists and packaging files for automatic Edje file compilation in project

Tags: cmake, packaging, efl

I'm very new to [EFL](http://www.enlightenment.org/p.php?p=docs&l=en). And now I'm trying to get used to it. There is library named Edje. This library allows theming and other sort of things. But files for it are created in plain text and have to be compiled using `edje_cc`.

How can I add this compilation to `CMakeLists.txt` file and to `packaging.spec` file for it to be properly compiled and installed on the machine?

Sorry for my broken English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CMakeLists.txt, do:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(your_edj_file.edj 
        COMMAND edje_cc your_edc_file.edc your_edj_file.edj
)
```

Notice that I simplified the COMMAND line - add the same arguments you use when you run edje_cc on a terminal (e.g. -id for images dir, -fd for fonts dir).

With this line added to CMakeLists.txt, a call to cmake in your packaging.spec file should be enough.