# Use of edje_cc in cmake file

Tags: c++, c, cmake, tizen, efl

I tried to add a custom target in a cmake file to compile a `.edc` file with edje_cc automatically on build like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500522/cmakelists-and-packaging-files-for-automatic-edje-file-compilation-in-project). Its part of an EFL project.

But I always get an error on compiling:

```
[    1s] [  0%] [ 50%] #### COMPILE EDC FILES ####
[    1s] make[2]: edje_cc: Command not found
[    1s] make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/edje] Error 127
[    1s] make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/edje.dir/all] Error 2
[    1s] make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Can someone please tell me what to do that the edje_cc compiler is found at compiling?

Comment: Do you have `edje_cc` available on your machine?  If not, you will need to get it installed.  Once you have `edje_cc` on your machine, you also need to ensure it is on your PATH, or create a script called `edje_cc` in a directory that is in your PATH that invokes the real `edje_cc` compiler in whatever location it is really installed, with any environment variables it requires set properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that edje_cc is not installed on your machine.
Modify CMakeLists.txt to add a check for finding edje_cc.

```
project("Edje")
find_program(EDJE_CC edje_cc)

if (NOT EDJE_CC)
   message(FATAL_ERROR "edje_cc is missing.")
endif()
```